# Get Date Pattern from the random string

Tags: java, date

I have a scenario to return "YYYYMMDD" from "v={YYYYMMDD}" with out using String literal methods like split, substring etc.

Is there anyway I can use the dateUtil methods or any regex?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `str.replaceAll("^v=\\{(\\d{8})\\}$", "$1")`

Comment: Yes, a regex should work.  Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) to find out how.  You'll need to know about `Matcher` and `Pattern`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not working, can you explain me the regex you have shared?

Comment: @GowthamiReddy [It is working](https://rextester.com/GLMPRQ5826?).  I cannot give you any further assistance.

Comment: Um, by "YYYYMMDD" did you mean eight numeric digits (presumably consisting of a four-digit year, two-digit month and two-digit day-of-month), or literally four letter Ys, followed by two letter M's, follwed by two letter D's?

Comment: @GowthamiReddy Using regex it is pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen thank you for the link but my requirement is not to return date. i need to return the pattern, not the date. v={YYYYMMDD} to YYYYMMDD not v={20190107} to 20190107

Comment: Oh.  If you really want to extract from the pattern itself then use `str.replaceAll("^v=\\{([^}]{8})\\}$", "$1")`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex -

```
String input = "v={YYYYMMDD}";
String regex = "^v=\\{([^}]{8})\\}$";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Date pattern - " + m.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("No date found!");
}
```

Result -

```
Date pattern - YYYYMMDD
```